# Как сделать выборку конкретного блока из <span> с помощью jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой html:

```
<div></div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<div></div>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
<span></span>
```

Количество спанов между `div` может быть произвольное количество, но всегда одинаково для блоков (если в первом 5, то и во всех последующих тоже).
Также заранее известно это количество (вводит пользователь).
Вопрос, как сделать выборку конкретного блока из `<span>`, другими словами, выбрать 3й блок из 10 `span`. Если в цикле:

```
jQuery("#afterSort2 div").eq(i).next("span");
```

то добирается ко всем первым `span`, которые идут после `div`, а мне надо ко всем `span`, после конкретного `div`.

Сразу скажу, что `html` генерируется на лету и как запихнуть `span` в `div` я не знаю (это бы могло решить проблему), я могу только расставить `div` или другой тег между блоками из `span` только для ориентира.

Дополню задачу, если кто знает как вывести из массива данные порциями, заключив порции в div, это также бы решило проблему. У меня получается вывести порциями, а в качестве разделителя установить произвольный тег, но к решению задачи это не приблизило.

Comment: Так что ли? `#afterSort2 div:eq(3) span`

Answer (score 1):

В jQuery цикле `$.each` параметром переданной функции является индекс найденного элемента, его можно использовать как счетчик кратности 3 например.

Например в верстке такого типа:

```
<div id="list">
 <div></div>
 <span>1</span>
 <span>2</span>
 <span>3</span>
 <span>4</span>
 <span>5</span>
 <span>6</span>
 <div></div>
 <span>7</span>
 <span>8</span>
 <span>9</span>
 <span>10</span>
 <span>11</span>
 <span>12</span>
</div>
```

вот так можно покрасить каждый 3 span в красный

```
$('#list span').each(function(index){
    if( (index+1) % 3 == 0) $(this).css('color','red'); 
});
```

Тогда просто проверять span ли текущий блок внутри

```
$("#list > *").each(function(){ 
    if( $(this).is('span') ) $(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: С чего Вы решили, что мне нужен каждый 3й или 4й или и т.д.? Мне надо: 1й-6й, потом 7-12, потом 13-18 и т.д.
Как добраться до каждого n-ного я знаю (именно так и расставляются div).

Answer (score 0):

Выбрать массив span-элементов внутри 3-го div-а внутри элемента с id `afterSort2`

```
$('#afterSort2 div:eq(2) span')
```

Пройтись по всем таким элементам и сделать их, например, красными:

```
$('#afterSort2 div:eq(2) span').each(function(s){
  s.css('color','red');
});
```

Comment: Не знаю, в чем проблема, но у меня :eq(i) не работает, только, если через точку
$('#afterSort2 div').eq(2) - работает, но не знаю как ко span добраться тогда.

Comment: И еще заметьте, у меня span находятся не внутри div.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
$('div:eq(2)').nextUntil( "div" ).text("2");
```

Answer (score -1):

Решил вопрос несколько иначе, используя цикл `do {} while ();` с делителем для отделения блоков со `span`. Вставки с `div` не пригодились. Добавляю код.

```
var icount = 1;
var icountflag = 0;
var intervalOutput = setInterval(function(){
    cleanFunc("#afterSort2");
    jQuery("#afterSort2 span").addClass("animated bounceInUp");
    do {
        tempOutput = "<span>" + bubblesMassiveAll[icount - 1] + "</span>";
        jQuery("#afterSort2").append(tempOutput);
        if (((icount % (bubblesCount) == 0) && (icount < bubblesMassiveAll.length))) {
            jQuery("#afterSort2").append("<div>");
        };
        if (icountflag!=0) {
            jQuery("#afterSort2 span").eq(icount -(icountflag+1)).css("height", 40+bubblesMassiveAll[icount-1]);
        } else {
            jQuery("#afterSort2 span").eq(icount -1).css("height", 40+bubblesMassiveAll[icount-1]);
        };
        icount++;
        } while ((icount-1) % (bubblesCount) != 0);
        icountflag += bubblesCount;
        if (icount >= bubblesMassiveAll.length) {
            clearInterval(intervalOutput);
            animateFunc("#afterSort2 span");
        };
    }, 1000);
```

Не до конца почистил, но суть ясна: через определенные интервалы (сейчас 1 секунда) выводит заданное количество тегов span.
Количество тегов спан - это переменная bubblesCount;
Теги имеют различную высоту 40px + номер, который генерится рандомно.
Как можно видеть, дивы код тоже проставляет, но я ими просто настроил отступы, можно убрать.
Да, код еще почищу, но это рабочий вариант.

Comment: Не согласен с двумя комментариями выше. Тут другая ситуация. Раз вы сами нашли решение, было бы здорово, если бы вы его опубликовали в этом ответе. Не только описание решения, но и существенные для решения участки кода.  Так ответ будет полезен будущим читателям (а вам репутация будет приходить потихоньку от них). Подробнее: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Я лично обязуюсь плюсануть вопрос и ответ, когда вы добавите код решения. Только сообщите — следить не имею возможности.